# Prevent ANY change to UICollectionView when keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview

I'm fighting with my `UICollectionView` for almost 2 days now and couldn't find much helpful info in the internet. Usually, people do want to have something scroll when a keyboard pops up.
I want the exact opposite!

Situation: Regular, plain `UIView` with a `UICollectionView` added as a subview. Then, in a certain event (tap a button of the `navigationbar`), a new subview is added with a `UITextView` in it.

For whatever reason, the collectionView that stays underneath this whole new view, thinks when I click the mentioned textView it has to do some weird scrolling up and down, along with tons of errors about broken **constraints**!

I just want it to stay where it is, not changing anything! It's not even visible (because a whole new view is above it, right).

*EDIT:*
My constraints are the following:

```
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: navBar)
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-20-[v0(44)][v1]|", views: navBar, collectionView)
```

This is how the subview is created and added:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.width, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
addSubview(view)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
    view.center.x -= self.frame.width
}
```

Part of the console output:

```
0x10a835a00; frame = (0 0; 375 617); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c405f0b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c4220640>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1500, 617}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 208, 0}>
```

It adds a bottom content inset of 208 and I have no idea why..

Thank you in advance!
Dave

Comment: Can you add some pictures and the used constraints?

Comment: The constraints are all in code. I'll add them now. (I don't use storyboards)

Comment: And are you adding the collection view to the view??

Comment: @iOSer yeah sure 

Comment: Lets say you have two view. 

We'll call this Base View - To this we will add the collection view
Now There's another view we'll call it Top View - to this we will add UITextfield.
Now we add both of these view to the self.view of the VC. keeping in mind the hierarchy of the subviews. Once the keyboard shows you only change the center x value of TopView rather than self.view. Are you sure youre doing the same

Comment: I'm not even changing the x value of the TopView.

Comment: hmmm possible to get the demo code? An image also would help alot

Comment: The code is posted in the question, I don't think more code will help. Probably, a collectionview automatically listens for keyboard did show events and I need to disable this.

Comment: dont know mate never heard of collection views automatically listening to keyboard show events. Maybe you can disable and enable scroll accordingly

Comment: the line view.center.x might auto refer to viewcontroller view? you think?

Comment: no, that refers to the "TopView" as you called it. This piece of code also works perfectly fine, that's definitely not the issue....

Comment: Xcode is known to be weird at times. Try closing it, deleting derived data and try again. You never know that might work too.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help. I also added part of the console output now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to switch the "outermost" Controller (that includes views that in turn control their own collectionViews) from a UICollectionViewController to a regular ViewController with a `lazy var collectionView` subview and having it conform to all the UICollectionViewController properties.
So this was not the controller for the collection view that I had issues with, it wasn't really related to those cells.
In my book, this is essentially a UICollectionViewController, so no idea why that worked but it did.
Kids, stick to UIViewControllers and UIViews for everything :D
All that fancy Apple-created specialized stuff tends to be buggy at times....